# Display a view of loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I user Swift2 and Xcode 7.1
I want to show my view loading by calling a function. My view chragement is a class that inherits from UIView.
I would like my class is instantiated throughout my Controller automatically.

My class :

```
class loading: UIView {

        let circle = UIView()
        let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        init() { }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func clear(){
            self.hidden = true
            // Animation ...
        }

        func display(){
            self.hidden = false
            // Animation ...
        }

        private func scaleAndColor(){ }

        private func createAnim(){ }

        private func createCircle(frame: CGRect){ }
    }
```

What I would like to :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // nothing to declare

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // nothing to do
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func anFunction(){
        load() // display my loadView
        clear() // clear my loadView
    }

}
```

Comment: is this a big loader that enables the user to use the screen?

Comment: It's just a view with a spinning wheel

Comment: If its going to be dependant on your top view then you should send the ViewController view on the load() method. But usually if you want to build a custom loaderView thats not dependant on any view they are singletons which are presented on top of the UIApplication keyWindow

Comment: Thank you ! And depending how singletons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Loader Singleton I built in Swift 2.1

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MGSwiftLoader: UIView {

    static let sharedInstance = MGSwiftLoader(frame: CGRectZero)

    private var backgroundView: UIView!
    private var label: UILabel!
    private let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //See through view
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.opaque = false

        //BackgroundView will contain the UIVisualEffectView, label and activityIndicator
        backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        backgroundView.opaque = false
        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.addSubview(backgroundView)
        backgroundView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(self)
            make.height.equalTo(100.0)
        }

        //Blur
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurredEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        blurredEffectView.clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundView.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
        blurredEffectView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(backgroundView)
        }

        //ActivityIndicator
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        backgroundView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.15, 1.15)
        activityIndicator.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(backgroundView)
        }

    }

    //Shows the loder - The view takes all the screen disabling touches but we only see the backgroundView with its subviews
    func show() {

        self.hidden = false


        //Take all of the MainWindow screen
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let frontWindow = application.keyWindow

        frontWindow?.addSubview(self)
        self.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(frontWindow!)
        }

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        //Show top activity indicator
        application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


        //Scale animation - you can add any animation you want
        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
        scaleAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
        scaleAnimation.duration = 0.33
        scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        self.layer.addAnimation(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scaleAnimation")
    }

    func showWithSubTitle(text: String) {

        show()

        if label != nil {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        activityIndicator.snp_remakeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.centerX.equalTo(backgroundView)
            make.centerY.equalTo(backgroundView).offset(-10.0)
        }

        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = text
        label.customFont(.Light, size: 15.0)
        backgroundView.addSubview(label)
        label.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.bottom.equalTo(backgroundView).offset(-10.0)
            make.right.equalTo(backgroundView).offset(-20.0)
            make.left.equalTo(backgroundView).offset(20.0)
        }
    }

    func hide() {

        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
        scaleAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
        scaleAnimation.duration = 0.33
        scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        scaleAnimation.delegate = self
        scaleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
        self.layer.addAnimation(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scaleAnimation")

        self.hidden = true

        //Hide top activity indicator
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

You just use it by calling:

```
MGSwiftLoader.sharedInstance.show()
```

or

```
MGSwiftLoader.sharedInstance.showWithSubTitle("Your Loader Text")
```

And hide it with:

```
MGSwiftLoader.sharedInstance.hide()
```

Keep in mind that I'm using SnapKit to build the constrains manually (http://snapkit.io)